# Configure a SSL cert and CNAME on website run on Azure IaaS, VM or cloud service?

Tags: azure, iaas

We have an website running on a Azure VM, the VM shares the same virtual network and cloud service with bunch of other servers, it is also reserved a public internet IP address. We need to configure our domain (***.abcd.com) and the SSL to the website. What's the best practice to do this?

With my limited knowledge of Azure, I was thinking to configure the CNAME to the static public IP then configure the SSL on the IIS. However, I was told to configure the SSL cert on the cloud service, also point the CNAME to the cloud service as well.

Please help, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are very confused about the differences of VMs, Cloud Services and Websites. If you have a VM, all you need to do is:

1. Create a record type A (host) in your public DNS server that points to your VM Cloud Service VIP.
2. Inside your VM, setup your IIS/Apache or whatever for SSL.
3. Add HTTPS endpoint

Although every VM has a Cloud Service, there's a big difference in deploying an aplication as a Cloud Service and the Cloud Service associated with your VM.

More info here:

http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/choose-web-site-cloud-service-vm/

Tip: You said you have a VM sharing a cloud service with a bunch of other servers. If all those VMs are not sharing the same core service, they should be running on their own Cloud Service.

Comment: thanks for the help! Two questions, a) "points to your VM cloud service vip", you mean I should point the CNAME directly to my reserved public IP for the VM right? b) for the SSL, do I have to do anything on the Azure cloud service configuration or simply the same compared to the on-premise configuration (only IIS) ... also, when I configure the SSL for on-premise network, there are two sets of SSL certificates, one is public external on DMZ, another is the internal one configured on intranet IIS, I was told it has to do that for safety concern, does it mean in Azure I don't need that?

Comment: a) forget CNAME. You only need to use CNAME if you don't have the public ip address, since it's not the case use an "A" record and point it to your reserved public ip. b) same as on-premise. Create a CSR. Send it to a Certificate Authority and complete the request. Should be good. Here's a good tutorial https://www.digicert.com/csr-creation-microsoft-iis-7.htm